# Does EntityFramework and DBContext work for Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Does EntityFramework and DBContext work for Oracle?
If yes, what do I have to look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, please have a look at this answer I just made: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710419/14533

I'm using EF 4.0 / .NET 4.5 and ODAC / ODP.Net v12 but I tried it with v11.2 of ODAC before it and worked too.